# How to send Postgresql DB trigger values to RabbitMQ queue as message?

Tags: python, postgresql, rabbitmq

My requirement is get values of db trigger and process them, so pg_notify is one option but I would need two listeners, one is pg_notify listener and one more RabbitMQ consumer (listener) which listen to queue messages and process them.

But I want a solution which can directly push db trigger values to queue as message, So I can reduce number of listeners / hops here. what I should use? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Maybe Debezium could solve the issue? https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/